# How can I allow multiple payment attempts through civicrm webform to prevent having to start from scratch if payment fails?

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor

We have a webform using the CiviCRM Webform integration which is allowing people to sign up for paid events. The webform is connected to a payment processor. When someones payment fails/gets declined then we would like them to get to attempt another payment for the same contribution.

Ideally they would get three attempts to cover for them putting in their details incorrectly or realising they need to top up their account.

Currently if the payment fails they must start again from scratch and reenter all the information again. This is what we are trying to avoid as it is annoying for the user if they have to put in all their details again.

Using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.7

Payment Processor is DPS (Payment Express) via the OmniPay extension

Comment: What Payment Processor are you using?

Comment: answered in answer ;-)